# Generic conforming a protocol array

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, protocols

For a unique object that conforms to a `ModelProtocol` protocol I can test generic with success by writing :

```
if let _ = T.self as? ModelProtocol.Type { /* Do some stuff */}
```

But I'm stuck if I need to test the conformity of `[ModelProtocol]` protocol. I tried :

```
if let _ = T.self as? [ModelProtocol.Type] { /* Do some stuff */}
```

But Xcode throws a warning :

> Cast from 'T.Type' to unrelated type '[ModelProtocol.Type]' always fails

How should I handle this case ?

Comment: Is `T` a generic parameter? If it is, have you considered adding generic constraints?

Comment: Yes it's a generic parameter and no I haven't

Comment: What do you mean by "*test the conformity of `[ModelProtocol]` protocol*"? `[ModelProtocol]` is an array, not a protocol. Do you mean you want to check whether `T` is `[ModelProtocol]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using generic functions with constraints. For example:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

protocol ModelProtocol {
    var name: String { get }
}

struct Model: ModelProtocol {
    let name: String
}

func myFunction<T: Sequence>(sequence: T) where T.Iterator.Element == ModelProtocol {
    for model in sequence {
        print(model.name)
    }
}

let models: [ModelProtocol] = [Model(name: "one"), Model(name: "two")]
myFunction(sequence: models)
```